# Ordering queries by deep paths with a variable key

Tags: angularjs, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my data structure in the database

```
"2017" : {
    "metadata" : {
      "February" : {
        "-Kc3BF0V1iLgtnI65LuR" : {
          "date" : "2017-02-04T13:36:38.311Z",
          "price" : 80
        },
        "-Kc3BF0V1xxfrtnI65OlS" : {
          "date" : "2017-02-11T13:36:38.311Z",
          "price" : 70
        },
        "-Kc3BF0V1xxfrtnIOZozp" : {
          "date" : "2017-02-03T13:36:38.311Z",
          "price" : 90
        }
      },
      "January" : {
        "-Kc3E5bpxpo3RpSHH3fn" : {
          "date" : "2017-01-01T13:50:12.264Z",
          "price" : 45
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  }
```

I am showing this data in a list in my ionic app like so

```
February
 + 2017-02-04
 + 2017-02-11
 + 2017-02-03
January
 + 2017-01-01
```

Now I want to sort the data under the months, so the data under February would become

```
February
 + 2017-02-03
 + 2017-02-04
 + 2017-02-11
```

I've [read in the firebase blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html#ordering-queries-by-deep-paths) that they've added a functionality that you can order queries by deep paths
But I can't find how you can query it when you have a dynamic key, in my case the months are the dynamic keys. As every child of the months need to be sorted by date.

I am retrieving the data from firebase with this snippet

```
 var dbRef = firebase.database().ref(year +  '/metadata/').orderByChild('date'); //How to order by date if my month is variable?
 return firebaseObject(dbRef);
```

I also tried ordering in angular using the orderBy filter, but that won't work as it needs to be an array. I found a [blog](http://justinklemm.com/angularjs-filter-ordering-objects-ngrepeat/) where they convert it to an array, but you will be losing the key, and I still need that because the list will be clickable so I can travel to it's details page. Also I don't think sorting on the front-end is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Database queries can only contain one dynamic path: the child directly under the location where you query. While `orderByChild()` can take a path to the property on which to order the data, that path must be static.

This means that if you want to query metadata across all months by date, you should keep a list of the metadata across all months:

```
"metadataList" : {
    "-Kc3BF0V1iLgtnI65LuR" : {
      "date" : "2017-02-04T13:36:38.311Z",
      "price" : 80
    },
    "-Kc3BF0V1xxfrtnI65OlS" : {
      "date" : "2017-02-11T13:36:38.311Z",
      "price" : 70
    },
    "-Kc3BF0V1xxfrtnIOZozp" : {
      "date" : "2017-02-03T13:36:38.311Z",
      "price" : 90
    }
    "-Kc3E5bpxpo3RpSHH3fn" : {
      "date" : "2017-01-01T13:50:12.264Z",
      "price" : 45
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: But with this datastructure I won't be able to show my list in the month/days view like I showed above. Isn't there an other approach or how can I still achieve the still I would like to have?

Comment: Correct. So if you want that use-case, you should *also* keep a list of the data by month. In NoSQL databases you'll often duplicate the data to allow the use-cases that your app needs. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).